How is badminton open level decided? (Super 1000, Super 750, Super 500,... etc)
I wonder how the levels of badminton open games are decided.
For example, why is Chinese Taipei Open only at level super 300 when it has practically the most players in BWF top 100 rankings in most of the categories?

According to Wikipedia, the sport's governing body hosts a review every four years to determine which countries get to host World Tour tournaments, and which levels those tournaments will be played at. The last one apparently took place ahead of the 2023 season, and saw the number of tournaments at each level expanded slightly.
I do not know the exact decision-making process behind this, nor am I aware of any public explanation for why the Taipei Open is only a Super 300 tournament.
